# UDP single vs multiple socket performance

Tags: java, sockets, web-applications, udp, static-libraries

In Java, what is the performance difference between the following two

1. Using single udp socket
2. Using multiple udp sockets

for multiple connections.

Although these details can be obtained over net , i need some expert advice.

**Exact Issue:**

we are providing a java library to be used in web application.Library methods can be accessed from jsp pages by creating objects for corresponding classes.Upon a method call , library will send udp request to third party server for response.

If jsp page A calls library method B then request-0  will be transferred to server for key-0.If key-0 is obtained , then further method calls will be ignored.Consider B is called 4 times.4 requests namely request-0 , request-1 , request-2 , request-3 are transferred to server.Since we are using udp which is connectionless , key-3 is received before other responses.Key-3 is not for request-0.So it is ignored.Then Key-0 is received.This is not for request-1.So it is ignored.Similarly all responses are ignored. Now the library has no idea on how to handle these responses. We are not blocking any request in library.We have doubt whether switching between multiple sockets to single socket will resolve this.

Comment: "If u need ,i can tell the exact issue which requires this information to be resolved."
Don't wait, tell us :)

Comment: As per your comment , i have edited the question.Please reply if you have any doubts.